# AWS S3 batch operation - Got Dinged Pretty Hard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

We used the newly introduced AWS S3 [batch operation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-batch-operations/) to back up our S3 bucket, which had about 15 TB of data, to Glacier S3 . Prior to backing up we had estimated the bandwidth and storage costs and also taken into account mandatory 90 day storage requirement for Glacier.

However, the actual costs turned out to be massive compared to our estimated cost. We somehow overlooked the UPLOAD requests costs which runs at $0.05 per 1000 requests. We have many millions of files and each file upload was considered as a request and we are looking at several thousand dollars worth of spend :(

I am wondering if there was any way to avoid this?

Comment: When you say "back up our S3 bucket", did you _copy_ the files to Glacier, or just change the Storage Class to `Glacier`? Are you goals for the backup to avoid accidental deletion, or to handle a potential S3 failure / file loss?

Comment: Have you contacted AWS Support?  They might be willing to help with some bill-shock such as this.  Now that you've incurred the charge I don't think an SO user can really help.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein They have introduced an automated batch service that looks at your bucket inventory and copies it to either another S3 bucket or to lower cost S3 Glacier. I chose the latter option. Purpose was to backup against accidental deletion since we only had 1 copy.

Comment: @A.J.Parr I have contacted AWS support and awaiting for the response. My question here for the community is whether there is any way to minimize the cost. The answer is probably NO but wanted to get input from more experienced users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of "backup" is quite interesting.

Traditionally, where data was stored on one disk, a backup was imperative because it's not good to have a **single point-of-failure**.

Amazon S3, however, stores data on multiple devices across multiple Availability Zones (effectively multiple data centers), which is how they get their **99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability**. (Note that durability means the likelihood of retaining the data, which isn't quite the same as availability which means the ability to access the data. I guess the difference is that during a power outage, the data might not be accessible, but it hasn't been lost.)

Therefore, the traditional concept of **taking a backup in case of device failure has already been handled in S3**, all for the standard cost. (There is an older *Reduced Redundancy* option that only copied to 2 AZs instead of 3, but that is no longer recommended.)

Next comes the concept of **backup in case of accidental deletion** of objects. When an object is deleted in S3, it is not recoverable. However, **enabling versioning on a bucket will retain multiple versions including deleted objects**. This is great where previous histories of objects need to be kept, or where deletions might need to be undone. The downside is that storage costs include *all versions* that are retained.

There is also the new **object lock** capabilities in S3 where objects can be locked for a period of time (eg 3 years) without the ability to delete them. This is ideal for situations where information must be retained for a period and it avoids accidental deletion. (There is also a **legal hold** capability that is the same, but can be turned on/off if you have appropriate permissions.)

Finally, there is the potential for **deliberate malicious deletion** if an angry staff member decides to take revenge on your company for not stocking their favourite flavour of coffee. If an AWS user has the necessary permissions, they can delete the data from S3. To guard against this, you should limit who has such permissions and possibly combine it with versioning (so they can delete the current version of an object, but it is actually retained by the system).

This can also be addressed by using **Cross-Region Replication** of Amazon S3 buckets. Some organizations use this to copy data to a **bucket owned by a different AWS account**, such that nobody has the ability to delete data from both accounts. This is closer to the concept of a true backup because the copy is kept separate (account-wise) from the original. The extra cost of storage is minimal compared to the potential costs if the data was lost. Plus, if you configure the replica bucket to use the **Glacier Deep Archive** storage class, the costs can be quite low.

Your **copy to Glacier** is another form of backup (and offers cheaper storage than S3 in the long-term), but it would need to be updated at a regular basis to be a continuous backup (eg by using backup software that understands S3 and Glacier). The "5c per 1000 requests" cost means that it is better used for *archives* (eg large zip files) rather than many, small files.

**Bottom line:** Your need for a backup might be as simple as turning on Versioning and limiting which users can totally delete an object (including all past versions) from the bucket. Or, create a bucket replica and store it in Glacier Deep Archive storage class.